# how to solve error in inline assembly in C: 'can't find a register in class 'GENERAL_REGS' while reloading 'asm''

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc, cryptography, inline-assembly

This is a part of implementation of lightweight cryptography PRESENT algorithm, optimized for speed, 8 bit, implemented by C, related to pLayer of the algorithm that implemented by inline assembly.

```
//  ****************** pLayer ******************************
        asm volatile("clr %0                \n"
                     "clr %1                \n"
                     "clr %2                \n"
                     "clr %3                \n"
                     "clr %4                \n"
                     "clr %5                \n"
                     "clr %6                \n"
                     "clr %7                \n"
                     "sbrc %8,0             \n"
                     "sbr  %0,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,1             \n"
                     "sbr  %2,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,2             \n"
                     "sbr  %4,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,3             \n"
                     "sbr  %6,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,4             \n"
                     "sbr  %0,2             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,5             \n"
                     "sbr  %2,2             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,6             \n"
                     "sbr  %4,2             \n"
                     "sbrc %8,7             \n"
                     "sbr  %6,2             \n"

                     "sbrc %9,0             \n"
                     "sbr  %0,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,1             \n"
                     "sbr  %2,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,2             \n"
                     "sbr  %4,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,3             \n"
                     "sbr  %6,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,4             \n"
                     "sbr  %0,8             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,5             \n"
                     "sbr  %2,8             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,6             \n"
                     "sbr  %4,8             \n"
                     "sbrc %9,7             \n"
                     "sbr  %6,8             \n"

                     "sbrc %10,0            \n"
                     "sbr  %0,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,1            \n"
                     "sbr  %2,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,2            \n"
                     "sbr  %4,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,3            \n"
                     "sbr  %6,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,4            \n"
                     "sbr  %0,32            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,5            \n"
                     "sbr  %2,32            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,6            \n"
                     "sbr  %4,32            \n"
                     "sbrc %10,7            \n"
                     "sbr  %6,32            \n"

                     "sbrc %11,0            \n"
                     "sbr  %0,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %11,1            \n"
                     "sbr  %2,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %11,2            \n"
                     "sbr  %4,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %11,3            \n"
                     "sbr  %6,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %11,4            \n"
                     "sbr  %0,128           \n"
                     "sbrc %11,5            \n"
                     "sbr  %2,128           \n"
                     "sbrc %11,6            \n"
                     "sbr  %4,128           \n"
                     "sbrc %11,7            \n"
                     "sbr  %6,128           \n"

                     "sbrc %12,0            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,1            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,2            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,3            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,1             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,4            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,2             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,5            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,2             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,6            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,2             \n"
                     "sbrc %12,7            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,2             \n"

                     "sbrc %13,0            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,1            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,2            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,3            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,4             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,4            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,8             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,5            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,8             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,6            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,8             \n"
                     "sbrc %13,7            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,8             \n"

                     "sbrc %14,0            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,1            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,2            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,3            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,16            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,4            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,32            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,5            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,32            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,6            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,32            \n"
                     "sbrc %14,7            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,32            \n"

                     "sbrc %15,0            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %15,1            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %15,2            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %15,3            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,64            \n"
                     "sbrc %15,4            \n"
                     "sbr  %1,128           \n"
                     "sbrc %15,5            \n"
                     "sbr  %3,128           \n"
                     "sbrc %15,6            \n"
                     "sbr  %5,128           \n"
                     "sbrc %15,7            \n"
                     "sbr  %7,128           \n"

                    :"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[0]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[1]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[2]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[3]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[4]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[5]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[6]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[7])
                    :"r"    (state[0]),"r"  (state[1]),"r"  (state[2]),"r"  (state[3]),"r"  (state[4]),"r"  (state[5]),"r"  (state[6]),"r"  (state[7])      
        );
```

in compiling of the code this error occurred:
"`can't find a register in class 'GENERAL_REGS' while reloading 'asm'`"

I searched about it and the reason and found some data, but didn't get how to solve this problem.

Is there any solution to define some registers for compiler or some especial syntax to correct the current code. some way except rewrite the code in another way?

thanks for your help.

Comment: What architecture are you targetting?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for more registers than the target architecture supports.  If the hw only supports (say) 8 registers, writing an asm statement that requires 16 is not going to work.  As for how to fix it: Use fewer registers.  Hard to be more specific without knowing more about your target architecture, but changing some of the parameters from "r" to "m" springs to mind.

Comment: @duskwuff in fact I didn't implement the code and it hadn't any instruction to explain. in addition I am new on such these codes and don't know how to change the current architecture.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you. but how can I use fewer register? is there any way to change compiling in a way that more register get? in fact the algorithm is complicated and I can't change this part of code easily.
changing "r" to "m" how can be possible? I got some new errors!

Comment: When duskwuff and I ask about architecture, we are trying to figure out whether you are compiling for x86, x64, arm, ia64, vax, etc.  Since (by definition) asm is architecture-specific, that's important.  "I got some new errors!" If someone came to you for help with a programming problem and that's ALL that they told you, could you help them?  Or would you have to ask "What errors?" You are asking people to help you with asm, but aren't saying WHOSE asm, and you want us to help fix your errors, but won't tell us what they are.  You shouldn't make it this hard for people to try to help you.

Comment: *"... optimized for speed, 8 bit, implemented by C..."* - I don't know the algorithm, but its been my experience 8-bit implementations are provided as reference implementations, and used for ASICs, Smart Cards and other constrained devices. They are always slower than their 32-bit or 64-bit counterparts by a factor of 2 to 8. If you are aiming for speed, then you want to avoid the 8-bit implementation.

Comment: Don't use inline assembly. Either program it in C and let the optimizer do its job, or if you can actually do a better job than the compiler write the entire function in standard assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to solve error in inline assembly in C: 'can't find a register in class 'GENERAL_REGS' while reloading 'asm''

And:

```
asm volatile("clr %0                \n"
             "clr %1                \n"
             "clr %2                \n"
             ...
         :"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[0]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[1]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[2]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[3]),
          "=&r"  (temp_pLayer[4]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[5]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[6]),"=&r"  (temp_pLayer[7])
         :"r"    (state[0]),"r"  (state[1]),"r"  (state[2]),"r"  (state[3]),
          "r"  (state[4]),"r"  (state[5]),"r"  (state[6]),"r"  (state[7])      
    );
```

I'm going to hazard a guess and say you ran out of general purpose registers.

Maybe you can use `g` rather than `r` in some places. According to [Machine Constraints | Simple Constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs//gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints), `g` is described as:

> Any register, memory or immediate integer operand is allowed, except
>   for registers that are not general registers.

Sometimes `rm` works too.